# One-to-Many relationship in Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, model, controller, one-to-many

I have two tables `Books` and `Authors`, where one book can published by **many** authors (One-to-Many)
`Book` model

```
class Book extends Model
{
    public function authors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Author::class); 
    }
}
```

`Author` model

```
class Auther extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
    }
}
```

The controller

```
public function index()
{
    $book = Book::all();
    return view('books.index',[
       'all_books' => $book, 
    ]);
}
```

The view

```
@foreach($all_books as $book)
   {{$book -> title}}
   {{$book -> date_of_publish}}
   {{$book -> add_by}}
   <!--show author name-->
   {{$book -> books ->name}}
@endforeach
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you display the errors

Comment: And include the model also in controller both one

Comment: ErrorException in ed82a00cfe9441d0910648577071959a61b32701.php line 41:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\library\resources\views\books\index.blade.php)

Comment: the model was included in controller

Comment: you have issue in the this kind variable you used "$book -> title" First check the $book result and check depth of the array and the use it. you can print array in laravel for use this function dd($book);

Comment: May be you have used like this $book[0]->title.

Comment: {{$book -> title}}
   {{$book -> date_of_publish}}
   {{$book -> add_by}}

Comment: You said that one book can be written by many authors, but does it mean that an author can only write one book ? If so your relation is ok and you just need to fetch the authors of a given book by looping over the `$book->authors` collection. If not you might need to consider a Many to Many relationship

Comment: i am sure problem is for this    {{$book -> books ->name}} . i know but i don't give solution instantly. otherwise you never learn. next time ask question before do the research about the your errors. Thanks enjoy the newly artisan.

Comment: I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me but im not able to comment yet as  shempignon says you need to call the $book->authors() method as all $all_books is an object of the Books::class this only has 1 method authors()

so to get the authors name you must do

```
@foreach($all_books as $book)
  {{$book->title}}
  {{$book->date_of_publish}}
  {{$book->add_by}}
  <!--show author name-->
    @foreach($book->author as $author)
      {{$author->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

and to get the book for each author you must do it the other way round $author->books()

Comment: it works correctly , but all books has connect with first record in authors table

Comment: im not sure what you mean what are the names of your tables and columns in your tables, as you might have to set the foreign key correctly